# Create grouped table with array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I found some answers that seemed close, but couldn't get them to work, so if someone has an answer to which they would like to point me if this is duplicate, I'm happy to go check it out. I have an array of objects that looks like this example:

```
[
    {Type:0001,Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
    {Type:0001,Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
    {Type:0001,Build:"heavy",Weight:4,Volume:1},
    {Type:0002,Build:"light",Weight:2,Volume:3},
    {Type:0002,Build:"light",Weight:2,Volume:3},
    {Type:0003,Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
    {Type:0003,Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
    {Type:0003,Build:"heavy",Weight:5,Volume:3},
    {Type:0004,Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1}
]
```

I created it using this:

```
let parseString = str => {
    let pairs = str.split(',');
    let obj = {};
    pairs.forEach(pair => {
        pair = pair.split(':');
        obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    });
    return obj;
};
```

I was able to parse the strings as needed to the array in the first block of code. That's less important, just wanted to point out a variable created by a for loop on some strings.

The array is returned in another function using push as "buildObjects". buildObjects is accessible to me in the HTML file I build for the front end display. we use Vue but just for the display. The viewer that we have combines the input js, HTML, CSS, and then combines a minified Vue file to render an HTML output. HOWEVER, I can't use normal Vue components, methods, etc...

What I need to do is to turn that data from above into a table like this:

```
Type    Build   Count   Weight  Volume
0001                            
        light   2       2       2
        heavy   1       4       1       
0002                    1       1
        light   2       4       6
0003                
        light   2       3       2
        heavy   1       5       3
0004
        light   1       1       1
```

I have to use Vue for the front end presentation and was trying to use v-for and row spans like this:

```
<tr v-for="buildObject in buildObjects">
    <td rowspan="4">{{buildObject.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{buildObject.Build}}</td>
    <td>{{buildObject.Count}}</td>
    <td>{{buildObject.Volume}}</td>                            
</tr>
```

but that wasn't working, which make sense.

What I really need is someone who can help me with the javascript, mind you, not components, computed components, etc, just javascript, to build the table like the one above, and also help with the HTML Vue part of this. I'm pretty stuck. I've gotten this far. I have a table built from this JSON data that came in with some funky formatting which required tons of manipulation in javascript just to get that array above. I am almost finished and am just...stuck. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `buildObjects` initialized to an empty array in the component `data`?  Anything referenced in the template has to be declared in the component script.

Comment: @Josef7 yes buildObjects is initialized to an empty array. It is being created correctly and returned as posted in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use Vue for the front-end presentation" without using components and computed properties.  Are you just using it for the templating, i.e. accessing variables in the template?  There are template engines like Thymeleaf that do that.  What engine are you using that wants a Vue template but not a Vue component?

Comment: @Josef7 some proprietary engine that I don't have access to. All I know is I return data to work with using javascript and then use Vue on the template. This was a part of a project I offered to help with as I had more javascript experience than the other team members and I am stuck.

Comment: Well at that point it sounds like you need to just write it in JavaScript. Vue isn't like jQuery or Bootstrap where you just include the source and everything works; your scripts have to be precompiled and injected along with the Vue code. If you can't use Vue components, it sounds like that's not happening. Not sure why else there would be a restriction like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with vue but you have to change buildObjects function to retrieve list like the below :

```
items = [
{Type:"0001",Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1,rowspan:3},
{Type:"0001",Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
{Type:"0001",Build:"heavy",Weight:4,Volume:1},
{Type:"0002",Build:"light",Weight:2,Volume:3,rowspan:2},
{Type:"0002",Build:"light",Weight:2,Volume:3},
{Type:"0003",Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1,rowspan:3},
{Type:"0003",Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1},
{Type:"0003",Build:"heavy",Weight:5,Volume:3},
{Type:"0004",Build:"light",Weight:1,Volume:1,rowspan:1}
];
```

and change your html code to equivalent the below angular code

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td  *ngIf="item.rowspan" [attr.rowspan]="item.rowspan" >{{item.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Build}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Weight}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Volume}}</td>                            
</tr>
```

PS: List should be sorted

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand if you have access to the Vue script. As you are using Vue at the front end, you should be abble to change your data structure by computed property, then iterate over it.

One example of implementation for what you try to achieve:

```
refactoredBuildObjects() {
    return Array.from(
        this.buildObjects.reduce((t, v) => {
            if (t.has(v.Type)) {
                const item = t.get(v.Type)

                if (item.Entries.has(v.Build)) {
                    const entry = item.Entries.get(v.Build)
                    entry.Weight +=  v.Weight
                    entry.Volume += v.Volume
                    entry.Count++

                    item.Entries.set(v.Build, entry)
                }
                else {
                    item.Entries.set(v.Build, { Build: v.Build, Weight: v.Weight, Volume: v.Volume, Count: 1 })
                }

                t.set(v.Type, item)
            }
            else {
                t.set(v.Type, {Type: v.Type, Entries: new Map([[v.Build, { Build: v.Build, Weight: v.Weight, Volume: v.Volume, Count: 1 }]]) })
            }

            return t;
        }, new Map()).values()
    ).map(item => {
        item.Entries = Array.from(item.Entries.values())
        return item
    })
}
```

I made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29cmj8ho/1/) for a full implementation.